# How to read user input into the subset command

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some R command like this

```
subset(
  (aggregate(cbind(var1,var2)~Ei+Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)),
  (aggregate(cbind(var1,var2)~Ei+Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean))$Ei == c(1:EXP)
)
```

I want to do

1) Ask the user to input the `var1` and `var2`

2) Get those variables into the subset command line as shown above and
 continue with other things.

Note: for reading the user input I have variables like
   `c(ax,bx,cx,dx,ex,fx,gx,hx,ix,jx,kx,lx,mx,nx,ox) = c(1:15)` and each
   variable is mapped to number 1 to 15. So displaying this for user and
   asking the user to select any number between 1 to 15 and then
   checking the corresponding variable for the entered number and
   reading this into the command line is whats the best method, I think.

So how can I implement this?

Regarding the answer:
Just wondering there is one possible scenario like , if the user wants to enter multiple of numbers in one go. [ex: 1,2,3]...than how to read this using readlines as said in the answer below using

```
v1 <- quote(var1 <- as.numeric(readline('Enter Variable 1: ')))
eavl(v1)
xx <- paste0(letters[1:15], 'x')
xx[v1]
```

How to read multiple variables in this case?

Comment: Why not to ask the user to fill a config file(csv or others) where you set all the parameters?

Comment: Oh that is a easy methode instead  of asking the user for options and then dealing with it. Actually I have 5 different options telling the user to select any one so that I can jump to the particular function and carry out the operation (all these 5 types are just different kind of plots, requiring different kind of user inputs), so basically I will be storing the values of csv inside a data frame and reading them accordingly and carrying out operations thats what you mean is it?

Comment: yes for example. You should also use function with default values parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough example of the `readline` interactive prompt. When `v1` is evaluated, the user will be prompted to enter a value.  That value is then stored as `var1`.

```
> v1 <- quote(var1 <- as.numeric(readline('Enter Variable 1: ')))
> eval(v1)
Enter Variable 1: 1000     ## user enters 1000, for example
> 100 + var1 + 50          ## example to show captured output as object
## [1] 1150
```

So in your case it might go something like

```
> v1 <- quote(var1 <- as.numeric(readline('Enter a number from 1 to 15: ')))
> eval(v1)
Enter a number from 1 to 15: 7
> var1
## [1] 7
> xx <- paste0(letters[1:15], 'x')
> xx
## [1] "ax" "bx" "cx" "dx" "ex" "fx" "gx" "hx" "ix" "jx" "kx" "lx" "mx" "nx" "ox"
> xx[var1]
## [1] "gx"
```

I borrowed this idea for a function from [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007178/creating-a-prompt-answer-system-to-input-data-into-r/11007431#11007431).  You can return the output invisibly and it will still take in the user values.

```
input.fun <- function(){
     v1 <- readline("var1: ")  
     v2 <- readline("var2: ")
     v3 <- readline("var3: ")
     v4 <- readline("var4: ")
     v5 <- readline("var5: ")
     out <- sapply(c(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5), as.numeric, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
     invisible(out)    
}

> x <- input.fun()
var1: 7
var2: 4
var3: 8
var4: 5
var5: 2
> x
[1] 7 4 8 5 2
```

**In response to your edit:**  I'm not sure if this is the standard method for reading multiple numbers in one line, but it works.

```
> xx <- readline('Enter numbers separated by a space: ')
Enter numbers separated by a space: 4 12 67 9 2
> as.numeric(strsplit(xx, ' ')[[1]])
## [1]  4 12 67  9  2
```

Comment: thanks thats simple...I did not expected..:)...I want to ask the user for 5 options and then divert the flow based on user selected option. So may I know is there a switch kind of function in R to do that ? or any simple method you suggest? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yeah..:) got it on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393508/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-r-functions                                         Thanks.

Comment: Haha, I was just looking at that.  I added something you might find useful.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner I posted a response to your edit

Comment: @RichardScriven That absolutely what I was looking for thanks..:)

Comment: No problemo.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility using `scan()`

```
#sample data
df<-data.frame(
    ax=runif(50),
    bx=runif(50),
    cx=runif(50),
    dx=runif(50),
    Ei=sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace=T)
)

#get vars
vars<-c(NA,NA)
while(any(is.na(vars))) {
    cat(paste("enter var number", sum(!is.na(vars))+1),"\n")
    cat(paste(seq_along(names(df)), ":", names(df)), sep="\n")
    try(n<-scan(what=integer(), nmax=1), silent=T)
    vars[min(which(is.na(vars)))]<-n
}
#--pause

#use vars
subset(aggregate(df[,vars], df[,c("Ei"), drop=F], FUN=mean), Ei=="a")
```

It's not super robust, but if you copy the first half (before the pause) it will ask you for two variable numbers, and then if you run the second half, it will use those two values. I've adjusted the `aggregate` and `subset` to be more appropriate for variable usage which means not using the formula syntax.

I did not do any error checking. That's left as an exercise for the asker.