# taking inputs through pop up window in R

Tags: r

I would like to read an input given by User in R programming through message window.

For example, It should give a message "enter the number" in a pop up box along with option of entering a number in the message box itself. Then I would like to store that number in a variable.

Thanks for your help in advance..!

Comment: There are lots of suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007178/creating-a-prompt-answer-system-to-input-data-into-r)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [svDialogs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svDialogs/index.html) provides such solution.

```
library(svDialogs)
user.input <- dlgInput("Enter a number", Sys.info()["user"])$res
```

which gives a pop-up as

[image: snap1]

Also, user input is stores

```
> user.input
[1] "68"
```

Comment: This does not work in a Jupyter Notebook.  It works fine from a RTerm command line.  Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you write a number, do not forget to convert using as.numeric(user.input) in order to be able to be used

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful. The $res confused me at the beginning, later I realised that  dlgInput() actually create a list, and res is an element within it.